# The given key was not present in the dictionary for TapGestureRecognizer

Tags: xaml, xamarin.forms

```
<render:CustomImageBorder x:Name="imgButtom" Source="{Binding CardImage}"               
HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"  >
    <render:CustomImageBorder.GestureRecognizers>
           <TapGestureRecognizer  Command="{Binding TabCommand}" NumberOfTapsRequired="1" />
    </render:CustomImageBorder.GestureRecognizers>
</render:CustomImageBorder>
```

kindly help me  to solve this problem .

Comment: Add your viewmodel code (CardImage, TabCommand)

Comment: To me how you added the `TapGestureRecognizer` looks fine. You should add the `CustomImageBorder` code.

Comment: Please add the Xamarin.Forms version you are using.

Comment: Thanks for replaying guys. I had solved my problem . The problem is in CustomImageBorder code.

Comment: if you explain the problem and the solution.. it could be a help for others who got the similar kind issues in future. regards.